# Are functions of dependent random variables also dependent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am aware of the fact that functions of independent random variables are also independent, but does similar reasoning apply to dependent variables?

Comment: Trivial counterexample: take a constant function $f$. (For instance, $f(x)=1$). Then, for any two random variables $X,Y$,
$f(X),Y$ are independent, and so are $f(X),f(Y)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no: Functions of dependent variables need not be dependent. For example, let $X$ and $Y$ be independent standard normal variables. Define $W:=X+Y$. Then $X$ and $W$ are dependent random variables (their covariance is $1$). But $X$ and $W-X$ are functions of $(X,W)$, and they are independent.